# Basic user input

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm working on learning some Assembly Language (x86 Irvine.32 windows7) and had a question about how to input from a user. The book I have doesn't go over it too in depth. I would like to prompt the user:

```
myfirst BYTE "Welcome! This program calculates the sum of a list of numbers.", 0dh, 0ah, 0dh, 0ah ; greeting 
        BYTE "How many integers will be added? : "
```

then the user will input X. How do I read what the user inputs and put it into a variable?

is it as simple as:

```
INVOKE ReadConsole, SomeVairable
```

Where SomeVairable is defined up in .data as a byte?

edit:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

BufSize = 80

.data
buffer BYTE BufSize DUP(?)
stdInHandle HANDLE ?
bytesRead   DWORD ?
myfirst BYTE "Welcome! This program calculates the sum of a list of numbers.", 0dh, 0ah, 0dh, 0ah ; greeting 
        BYTE "How many integers will be added? : "
mysecond BYTE "Please enter the "

.code
main PROC

    mov edx, OFFSET myfirst                         ;move the location of myfirst into edx
    call WriteString    

    ; Get handle to standard input
    INVOKE GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    mov stdInHandle,eax

    ; Wait for user input
    INVOKE ReadConsole, stdInHandle, ADDR buffer,
      BufSize, ADDR bytesRead, 0


    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523185/a-simple-assembly-input-question

Comment: @PavanManjunath: Probably not much help -- that's written for DOS, but this is for Windows. From a viewpoint of assembly language-level programming, the two don't really have all that much in common.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not (at least usually) that simple.

What the user enters will be read as a *string*, not a number. You'll typically have to read the string (which will usually be more than one byte long), then convert it to an integer. You may want to verify that all the characters in the string are digits before you do the conversion, or you may want to combine conversion with verification.

Looking specifically at the `ReadConsole` call, there are two things to keep in mind. First, you need to retrieve a handle to the console, normally with [`GetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231.aspx). Then, you need to supply [`ReadConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958.aspx) with all of the half dozen or so parameters it expects.`

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. Ill edit my code but another question I have is if im writting a string how can I put the variable that the person entered into the string? Would I have to output 2 strings? 1 string saying "Please enter " then the variable "5" then another string "numbers" So when it comes out together it's "Please enter 5 numbers"

Comment: @Nogg: yup, that's pretty much it.